# Retrieving array object inside a ComboBox object

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, java-8, combobox

```
public class AddressSelector{

    private String name;
    private AddressInternalType[] types;
}

private ComboBox<AddressSelector> lvlTwoDen;


lvlTwoDen.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

    AddressItemExt address = lvlOneAddress.getValue();
    if(address != null){
        setupLvlTwoName(ServiceUtil.getAddress(address.getCode(), lvlTwoAddress.getEditor().getText() + "*", lvlTwoDen.getValue().getTypes()));
    }
});
```

I have a comboBox of a specific object. In that comboBox object i have an array  object which I want to retrieve. I tried the following code snippet using `lvlTwoDen.getValue().getTypes()` however `lvlTwoDen.getValue()` returns null. How can I retrieve the Types from the combobox ?

EDIT :

I have 2 comboboxes. lvlOneDen and lvlTwoDen. On selection of a value from lvlOneDen i am setting a value in lvlTwoDen successfully using `lvlTwoDen.getSelectionModel().select(0)`.

like this :

```
lvlOneSiruta.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldVal, newVal) -> {

                lvlTwoDenom.getSelectionModel().select(0);
});
```

However, since I'm just selecting the value in lvlOneDen and haven't clicked and selected any value in lvlTwoDen, I get lvlTwoDen.getValue() as null. Is there a way to set a 'value' for lvlTwoDen on selection of a value in lvlOneDen ?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: hello @kleopatra, I have added an EDIT. Maybe that would help ?

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly ..